# nestjs set number of partition for kafka client

Tags: typescript, apache-kafka, nestjs

is there any way to pass the number of partition to kafka client configuration?

I'm using out of the box kafka client of nestjs like the following:
producer & consumer code:

main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.connectMicroservice(
    {
      transport: Transport.KAFKA,
      options: {
        client: {
          clientId: 'app1',
          brokers: ['localhost:9092'],
          logLevel: logLevel.ERROR,
        },
        producer: {
          allowAutoTopicCreation: true,
          retry: {
            retries: 10,
            multiplier: 2,
          },
        },
        consumer: {
          groupId: 'app1',
        },
        run: {
          autoCommit: false,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      inheritAppConfig: true,
    },
  );
  await app.startAllMicroservices();
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

controller

```
@MessagePattern('event1')
  async event1Handler(@Payload() data: any, @Ctx() context: KafkaContext) {
    console.log(`receive ${data.arg} - part: ${context.getPartition()}`);
    await context.getConsumer().commitOffsets([
      {
        topic: context.getTopic(),
        partition: context.getPartition(),
        offset: context.getMessage().offset,
      },
    ]);
  }
```

when the producer & consumer run they create a topic in kafka with 1 partition
I need to create more than 1 partition for topic throught kafka client,
is there any way to pass the number of partition to kafka client?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your Kafka `server.properties` to change `partitions=1`...

Otherwise, you need to manually use KafkaJS `AdminClient` class to create topics, separately from NestJS config (i.e. before calling `bootstrap()`)